# EBICS : Send HPB request with php

Tags: php

I try to send EBICS HPB request, but get always the same error:

> EBICS_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED

I think the problem is on my code, below is what the code is doing to get the signature value :

1. Get signature Certificate from pem file
2. Remove CR, LF and Ctrl-Z
3. Convert PEM to DER.
4. Apply ISO10126
5. hash sha256
6. Encryption rsa PKCS #1 v1.5: rsa_encrypt($SignatureValue, $public_key)

Then I put the result as signature value, but I'm not sure to do the right procedure before sending my request.